# vb.net MySQL and Arabic characters

Tags: mysql, vb.net, character-encoding

I have a MySQL database in a Linux server , character-set=utf8
collation=utf8_unicode_ci ..
write/read Arabic characters with php is fine , no issues ever ..
however when reading the database data directly from the server using webmin it shows something like this :     Ã˜Â§Ã™â€žÃ™ ..... 
anyway , I didn't care about that cause reading/writng in Arabic from php was perfect ..

now I'm trying to read with VB.net .. connecting like this :

```
MySqlConnection.ConnectionString = "server=x.x.x.x; user id=xx; password=xx; database=xx; CharSet=utf8 "
```

the output is like this :Ø§Ù„Ù…ÙˆØ¶Ùˆ
trying many solutions like :

```
bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(result)
arabic= Encoding.GetEncoding(xxxx).GetString(bytes)
```

without any success !!!
I need help please ..

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED BY :

```
bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-16BE"), Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ids))
arabic = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-16BE").GetString(bytes)
```

Comment: You should not need any form of 'convert'.  See "Mojibake" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored